# date.now() always returns the same time in mongodb pipeline subtract?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs, pipeline

I was in charge of the backend work made of nestjs, and I am providing lists and posting detail view api for posting articles.
Among the values ​​to be exposed, you need to provide how much time has passed by calculating the uploaded time and the current time.
For this calculation, subtraction was used in mongodb's pipeline. In the detailed view api, it is properly extracted, but in the api that exposes the list, the current time is calculated as the same as the time when the first request was made, so the same value is extracted.
However, if I turn the server off and on, the current time refreshes again, but it's the same after the first request.

I heard that Date.now() continues to use the object created when the server started, so I tried new Date() and Date.now, but it still doesn't work.

The error pipeline is below

```js
export const GetRecentVideoListPipeLine = [
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'nickName': 1,
            'thumbNailPath': 1,
            'title': 1,
            'tags': 1,
            'likeCount': 1,
            'uploadedAt': {
                '$subtract': [
                    Date.now(),
                    '$uploadedAt'
                ]
            },
        }
    },
    { '$sort': { 'uploadedAt': 1 } }
];
```

But, this works fine

```js
export const GetVideoDetailPipeLine = (videoId: string) => {
    return [
        { '$match': { '_id': new ObjectId(videoId) }},
        { '$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'nickName': 1,
            'title': 1,
            'tags': 1,
            'likeCount': 1,
            'videoPath': 1,
            'uploadedAt': {
                '$subtract': [
                    Date.now(),
                    '$uploadedAt'
                ]
            }
        }}
    ]
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you have a constant object, that is evaluated at start time of your code and is re-used without being re-evaluated. In the second snippet you have a method, which is evaluated at call time of the method, meaning the value is re-evaluated at each call. It's the difference of something like

```js
const now = Date.now()
console.log(now)
console.log(now)
console.log(now)
```

vs

```js
const now = () => Date.now()
console.log(now())
console.log(now())
console.log(now())
```

The first set of `now`s are static and only change on each run of the script. The second set of `now`s are dynamic and change not only with each run of the script, but with each execution on the function